# How to implement GroupBy using linq in razor view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How can this nested grouping be implemented in razor view?

This is what i have tried

Controller

```
public ActionResult SeniorityList()
{
    var employee = db.Employees.GroupBy(f => f.Facility.FacilityName).ToList();
    return View(employee.ToList());
}
```

However I don't know how to implement the `foreach` loop in view

Comment: There is no need to `.ToList()` twice. But in any case, you grouping data so it should be `.ToDictionary()` - `.GroupBy()` returns a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>>`

Comment: Please also note that the model-view-controller tag is for questions about the pattern. There is a specific tag for the ASP.NET-MVC implementation.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want the grouped data, i suggest you create a new class for that

```
public class GroupedItem
{
    public string GroupName { set; get; }
    public IEnumerable<Employee> Items { set; get; }
}
```

Now you can use the GroupBy method on your `db.Employees` collection and project the results to a collection of GroupedItem class objects.

```
var grouped = db.Employees
                .GroupBy(f => f.Facility.FacilityName,i=>i,
                                (key,v)=>new GroupedItem  { GroupName = key,Items = v})
                .ToList();
return View(grouped);
```

the type of `grouped` variable will be a list of `GroupedItem` and we are passing that to the view. So make sure that your view is strongly typed to a collection of `GroupedItem` class.

```
@model IEnumerable<GroupedItem>
@foreach (var group in Model)
{
    <h3>@group.GroupName</h3>
    foreach (var p in group.Items)
     {
         <p>@p.Name</p>
     }
}
```

Comment: can this class allow for nested groupBy, i mean havein upto two or three fields grouped